# SQL - faster way to UPDATE column entries

Tags: mysql, database

I have a SQL table similar to the following:

```
id | text | other_columns...
----------------------------
 0 |  a   |      ...
 1 |  b   |      ...
 2 |  c   |      ...
```

I need to apply some complex operation to the values in the `text` column, and then update the fields with the new values.

```
 // Get all the current values.
 entries = SELECT id,text FROM foo_table;

 // Apply some complex operation to the text values (this part is Python, not SQL).
 foreach entry in entries
     entry.text = f(entry.text)

 // Update the text fields (1 UPDATE per entry).
 foreach entry in entries
     UPDATE foo_table SET text=entry.text WHERE id=entry.id;
```

This results in a table like this, with updated text values:

```
id | text | other_columns...
----------------------------
 0 |  x   |      ...
 1 |  y   |      ...
 2 |  z   |      ...
```

It takes ~1 ms per UPDATE, and I have ~.5 million entries which results in ~8 minutes of execution. I am batching the SQL commands (1000 at a time), but this still seems very slow/inefficient.

Is there a better (faster) way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: What is the complex operation (if you can tell us)? Maybe it can be done in SQL and that definitely will speed it up.

Comment: Can u provide data create stmt with indexes shown

Comment: @PabloGonzálezAlba The 'complex operation' is doing a bunch of custom string tokenization/substitution and referencing external data sources. Unfortunately it cannot be done in SQL (and even if it could be done, it is prohibitively expensive to re-implement in SQL).

Comment: @DrewPierce Not sure I understand your request. Do you mean data types? `id` is an `int`/`primary key`, and `text` is a `varchar`. Lots of additional columns in the table with varying data types.

Comment: @smg Ok. You should make sure that the `id` field has an index and you could look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27743541/1624032) to send all statements in one shot to see if it helps. I can't think of any other improvement.

Comment: @PabloGonzálezAlba Thanks for trying. Unfortunately I'm already using `executemany`.

Comment: Are you running this code on the SQL server or are you pulling this data across a network and onto another machine to process?

Comment: Ugh. Turns out my `id` column was not indexed properly. This was causing my `WHERE id=` to slow down the entire query. Creating a unique index for the `id` column increases my performance x100 fold. Thanks all for your time and leading me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export to txtfile with 2 columns thru OUTFILE export.

```
SELECT id, theText
  INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/file.csv'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM myTable
```

Have Py do an in out of it.

Can have 2 columns or 3. Let's say 3 for debugging purposes.

Now u have the out. Bring back into mysql with an INFILE into a worktable with id,newText.

```
    LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE worktable
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
      LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Note that the data to import can have row1 with column names. Row1 can be skipped for data import of course, but by naming columns you bring in only certain columns. In your case 2 out of 3 columns.

Add index on worktable.id AFTER import.

Update will be fast.

```
UPDATE myTable
JOIN worktable
ON worktable.id=myTable.id
SET myTable.text=worktable.newText
```

This entire thing can occur in an enclosed bash script. If not sure how please ask.

Comment: Yeah, you could have a stored procedure in SQL that takes an entire table as a parameter, then updates the target table with the stored procedure's table.  This would let you pull the entire table into your python code, make all the changes, then update all at once.

Comment: I know, I'm saying have Python call the stored procedure and pass in the table as a parameter.

Comment: @DiscipleMichael show that in code. I am sure smg the OP would like to see your mock-up, me too. You have an Answer slot below in your Answer to show the details.

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something big here, but why can't you just do

```
Update foo_table;
Set foo_table.text = f(foo_table.text)
```

Comment: Right, but if he's actually calling the function f() in the SQL code, he should be able to do this too.  Perhaps, he was just simplifying a call to the function for brevity's sake?

Comment: I don't think so. He was probed about it

Comment: I'm using `f` to abstract the operation away from this question. `f` is actually some complex function that's being applied in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a UDF but you have to rewrite your function in C.