# Django Transaction.atomic() Vs SQLAlchemy session for bulk update

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlalchemy, orm

I'm trying to find the best way to bulk update a MySQL DB using python

the current ways I have are:

```
req_model.objects.bulk_update(update_queries, list(column_to_update))
```

in this method, the problem is the fetching part required for the `update_queries`
which is a list of updated objects of the model

through internet scouring, I found out about Django's transaction.atomic():

```
with transaction.atomic():
  for key, value in user_ids_dict:
    model.objects.filter(id=key).update(some_value=value)
```

another issue with this is that Django doesn't support composite primary keys other than specifying them in the metaclass

the other method (which I currently use) is using SQLAlchemy sessions(this works but its very slow due to server limitations):

```
self.init_session()
self.execute_bulk_update(model, mappings)
self.session.commit()
```

model is a list of dicts that contain updates and mappings is an SQLAlchemy model
is atomic() faster than the session?

I'll also gladly accept any other better suggestions for bulk-updating tables.

Comment: Please show us the generated SQL; we can more easily determine the performance from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use simple python by connecting with your MySQL DB rather than django or flask sqlalchemy orm. Take a look into this post this might help you.

[Bulk update MySql with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006202/bulk-update-mysql-with-python)

Comment: thanks for the response, i've not considered this approach before. ill give it a shot and get back :).