# Update multiple rows in mysql table with single call

Tags: python, mysql, django, pandas

I have a table in MySql DB. I need to update a particular column for all the rows in the table.
I need to do this in a single call without deleting the rows, only updating the column values.

I have tried using df.to_sql(if_exists='replace') but this deletes the rows and re-inserts them. Doing so drops the rows from other table which are linked by the foreign key.

```
merge_df = merge_df[['id', 'deal_name', 'fund', 'deal_value']]
for index, row in merge_df.iterrows():
        ma_deal_obj = MA_Deals.objects.get(id=row['id'])
        ma_deal_obj.deal_value = row['deal_value']
        ma_deal_obj.save()
```

merge_df has other columns as well. I only need to update the 'deal_value' column for all rows.

One solution I have is by iterating over the dataframe rows and using Django ORM to save the value but this is quite slow for too many rows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update multiple rows with single MySQL query in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27743447/how-to-update-multiple-rows-with-single-mysql-query-in-python)

Comment: So are you saying you need to execute `UPDATE MA_Deals SET deal_value = 'new-value';`

Comment: @MarlinPierce No, that would make the value of deal_value = 'new-value' for all rows, I need to set different values of deal value for each row. Something like
UPDATE MA_Deals SET deal_value = 'new-value1' where id = 1;
UPDATE MA_Deals SET deal_value = 'new-value2' where id = 2;
UPDATE MA_Deals SET deal_value = 'new-value3' where id = 3;
All this but in a single call
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27743447/how-to-update-multiple-rows-with-single-mysql-query-in-python) is what I was looking for.